# Change grub order in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

**Hello** I have a Dualboot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 and I use Ubuntu grub so the grub is like this:-

```
                                        Grub [Its version]
1) Ubuntu
2) Advanced option for Ubuntu 
3) Windows boot loader
4) UEFI Configuration
```

So I want to change it to this :- is it possible?

```
                                            Grub [Its Version]
1) Windows Boot Loader
2) Ubuntu 
3) Advanced option for Ubuntu
4) UEFI Configuration
```

And also after updates the grub is updated everytime so will it revert it to the previous even if I changed it? Thankyou.

Comment: Can you explain more feel free to put it in answer I will try it. But I want a safe method.@UnKNOWn

Comment: Plz ignore my first comment. Thanks

Comment: Its Ok I will try grub-customizer because the terminal methods seems complicated. 
 Also will it get to its default again after regular updates because I saw in details while installing updates that it always update the grub.Thanks. @UnKNOWn

Comment: I also found this site https://itsfoss.com/grub-customizer-ubuntu/ and its more easier now to understand.@UnKNOWn